# Getting the parent pages of Page DataObject in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am developing a SilverStripe project. Now I am trying to get the Page object by ID in the controller like this.

```
$currentPage = Page::get()->byID($this->ID);
```

Also, I want to all the parents/parent of the $currentPage too. But I cannot find related columns in the database table for Page like parent_page_id or whatsoever. How can I get all the parent pages of Page data object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Page is broadly speaking a SiteTree object. The `ParentID` column exists on the `SiteTree` database table. You can access a page's parent like so:

```php
$parent = $currentPage->Parent();
```

You can also use `SiteTree::getParent()` for the same result:

```php
$parent = $currentPage->getParent();
```

If you need to get all parents recursively, you can do that in a loop until `->Parent()` returns falsy.

Also, as `SiteTree` uses `Hierarchy` for the Parent/Children logic, you can also use `getAncestors()` to get all parents and grandparents. See [the API documentation](https://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/ORM/Hierarchy/Hierarchy.html#method_getAncestors).

Comment: As SiteTree uses Hierarchy for the Parent/Children logic, you can also use `getAncestors()` to get all parents and grandparents. See [api docs](https://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/ORM/Hierarchy/Hierarchy.html#method_getAncestors)

Comment: @wmk thanks, I've converted the answer into a community wiki and added your suggestion